# android studio Error Execution failed for task :app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex

Tags: android

i've been receiving this error since yesterday, i dont know how to solved, i already check and try every single similar topic i could find but nothing solve the problem, hope you can give an idea to solve it. the entire error says:

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/jcraft/jsch/agentproxy/AgentProxy.class
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.luiggi.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-1-7-4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jxl.jar')
    compile files('libs/poi-3.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/androidplot-core-0.6.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
}
```

Comment: This error occurs when you have included a dependency more than once.

Comment: can you tell me wich dependency i include more than once? i already try deleting play-services and leaving play-services-maps and same error

Comment: The error points to this `com/jcraft/jsch/agentproxy/AgentProxy.class`. I am not sure which dependency contains this class. Can you check if the dependencies in the `build.gradle` file and libs folder both put together don't have any duplicates?

Comment: already check on libs folder , i had like 5 agentproxy files, i moved all to desktop and build gradle and now the error is: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: net/sf/cglib/core/AbstractClassGenerator$1.class